# How can I fetch the features with less than X number of words in their Acceptance Criteria in Azure DevOps board?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to fetch list of Features having less than say 10 words in their Acceptance Criteria. However, the ADO queries are not allowing me to do that filtering. How can I solve this?

I tried ADO queries but when I choose Acceptance Criteria as Filter it is only allowing me to search by words but not filter by the count of words.